Is there a model of ZF not C where not every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable?
I know that there is a model of ZF set theory plus the negation of the axiom of choice where every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable. But is there also a model where not every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable? If so, can someone give me the proof?

A more exact duplicate over on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/73902/2126
